# Pebble SDK Python script: command not found

Tags: macos, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I have downloaded/installed the Python libraries as instructed on Pebble's installation site (OS 10.9.1, Pebble SDK 2), but when I try to run

```
pb-sdk.py create-project
```

in order to create a new project together with its metadata file, I get the error:

```
pb-sdk.py: command not found
```

I'm not familiar with Python, or indeed much else outside of Xcode, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: out of curiosity, where did you find references to pb-sdk.py?

Comment: Sorry, can't find it again (a search took me to SDK1 pages, maybe there?) but it was on the Pebble developers site, shortly before Beta6 appeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pb-sdk.py` was the name of the tool used to control the SDK in very early versions. You need to call `pebble new-project` now.

You will find examples in the [Pebble Getting Started Guide](https://developer.getpebble.com/2/getting-started/hello-world/)